# jquery fails in load callback function

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, load

I have been reading several questions about this, but I didn't find the solution for my problem. Sorry if I'm repeating something that as been asked before.

In the code:

```
$("#menuZone").load("northMenu.jsp", function(response, status, xhr) {
                if (status == "error") {
                    var msg = "Error found: ";
                    alert(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                }else{
                    // hide admin menus
                    $('.admin').hide();
                }
            });
```

What I'm trying to do is loading an unordered list from **'northMenu.jsp'** and hide the items (li tags) that have class `admin`.

In the code above, the items with that `class` are *not been hided*, but the full `html` is inserted perfectly in `#menuZone`.

After that, calling functions elsewhere to show and hide that items, works OK.

In [jquery load doc](http://api.jquery.com/load/) says, *"If a complete callback is provided, it is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed"*.

So, the problem should not be an asynchronous question! Or could it?

Comment: why not use css to hide that instead

Comment: Just because I think jQuery give us a quick way to do it, with '.hide()' and '.show()'. For a dynamic perspective, jQuery way seems to be good.

Comment: @ricardoc, do the `.admin` elements appear verbatim in the loaded markup, or does that markup contain scripts that, in turn, create the elements?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the children of `#menuZone` to see if jQuery is looking at what you want correctly?

Comment: well you can use jquery to show it when needed and hide after. but if you use css to hide it at the start, you won't have issues anymore

Comment: And are you saying that other attempts to call this function elsewhere whilst using the `.admin` have been successful?

Comment: In the generated page source code, only appears '<div id="menuZone"></div>'. Nothing inside... But when the '$('.admin').hide()' (or show) are called by other Ajax callback functions, in different parts of the code, the items are correctly displayed or hided!

Comment: So, Sethen, the answer is yes. The other attempts are successful. Huangism, the css way is a solution for this, probably, but I want to understand what is failing here with the load method, to prevent problems again in future.

Comment: Hamidi, I found with Firebug, that all elements are in DOM.

Comment: @ricardoc, I was not referring to the DOM, but to the markup you receive from the AJAX request. Does it contains the actual list items? Or does it contain `<script>` blocks that create the list items? I'm asking this because `load()` shouldn't exhibit this problem, and I suspect scripts that are executed when the loaded markup is injected into the page do not run immediately.

Comment: Hamidi, I didn't understand! Sorry. But I saw now in Firebug, and all 'li' elements are returned from Ajax response.

Comment: @ricardoc, I cannot repro this with jQuery 1.7.2 on my hopelessly outdated Firefox 8. Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qMyzu/) for you to try. Does it work in your browser?

Comment: Yes, it works in my browser too. But there are some differences to my code. I don't know if they are relevant. My Ajax loaded page includes scripts like '<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/js/fg.menu.js"></script>' and '$(function() { $('#menu2').menu({...}); }'. In parent page, the target element is a 'div', not a 'ul'. The 'ul' is returned by Ajax too.

Comment: @ricardoc, I don't think any of these factors can cause your problem, and the fiddle is working for you so this is not a browser issue. We're at 14 comments so far, so I guess I'll try and go for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qMyzu/) is working for you, it does not seem to be an issue with your browser. Assuming nothing in your code is tampering with `load()` (a reasonable assumption IMHO), that only leaves two possible explanations:

1. `$(".admin")` matches nothing because the markup coming from the AJAX request does not contain `class` attributes, and these attributes are added by code somewhere down the line.
2. The elements are actually hidden, but are shown again immediately afterwards by another part of the code (you mentioned other AJAX requests being performed in your question's comments).

Therefore, I'd suggest you instrument your `complete` callback by adding an `alert()` call:

```
// Hide admin menus.
$(".admin").hide();
alert($(".admin").length);
```

There are three possible outcomes:

- The alert prints `0`, which means *(1) is true*.
- The alert prints a number greater than `0`, in which case:

  - Without dismissing the alert box, check if the `.admin` elements are visible,

    - If they aren't, then *(2) is true*.
    - If they are, then *something else I failed to think of is true*.

Comment: Well, this is a very complex question... The alert prints 2, so (1) is false. But I can't check if elements are hidden, because they're elements in a submenu. To access them I need to close alert window. But if I add class 'admin' to the top level menu (title), then this menu is not shown (correctly). Another curiosity is that if I put '.admin{display: none;}' in CSS file, the 'li' elements are not shown, as expected.

Comment: The other Ajax calls with functions to show and hide this elements are executed only in user login and logout. So, after menu is full loaded. As I said before, CSS way is a solution, but I was trying to understand the problem with load(), to prevent future issues in apps. But thank you for your help.

Comment: My guess is that this problem is some conflict between my jquery 'hide()' and the instructions that come from the plugin 'fg.menu.js'. And that declaration in CSS is at an higher level than jquery methods.

Comment: @ricardoc, indeed, since the elements reside in hidden submenus, my best guess would be that the menu plugin you're using unconditionally shows all the submenu items, disregarding the `admin` class. If that's the case, and you cannot filter the menu items to show with a plugin option, you can modify the plugin itself and package this custom version with your code.